# Adding buttons on xml file other than main

Tags: java, android

I have two xml files in my application - **main.xml** and **options.xml**.

In both of them I use buttons. The problem is, that while interacting with the buttons in **main.xml**, I cannot do that with **options.xml**: if I write

```
Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b1);
```

, b is going to be null. What is the cause of this problem and how do I fix it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Probably you set `main.xml` like `setContentView(R.layout.main)`, but what do you do with `options.xml`? Consider to post some code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to either inflate the options.xml or set it as content view:

```
setContentView(R.layout.options);
```

before you can use the views in that layout file.

It sounds like you want to be able to access both layouts so you should do something like this:

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.options, null);
Button b = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.b1);
```